# Really Weird Search Error

Tags: search, redirect, catalogsearch

Elasticsearch 7, Magento 2.4.5 p1, running on a vps Centos7 WHM, test done with 3rd party search engines disabled. All caches cleared, and re-indexed. Also ran test with 3rd party search extension enabled with same results. Same results on test site and live site on seperate Cpanel accounts.

Problem: ANY search term ending in "ing" will redirect straight back to the last page visited

Example: Cut, Cutt and Cutti give expected results. Cutting will not work
Example: Sand works, Sanding will not
Example: Premier, Exterior, Exterior Cut all work
Example: Bong works, Bing will not work
Example; Endong will work, Ending will not

I have tried adding symonyms but no luck. I cannot even add the search term to a url ie

catalogsearch/result/?q=cut will work but typing catalogsearch/result/?q=cutting redirects to last page and changes url as if it wasn't typed at all. No "ing" words will get added to the search terms in admin either.

There are also no redirects associated with "ing" and no errors listed in any log including cpanel, VAR and root folders.

I must admit, I am absolutely stumped. Couldn't see this being database corruption just on "ing" And I've no idea when this started, it was luckily picked up by one of our sales guys by chance.

Hoping you guys may have some other ideas.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure it would explain that behavior but is there any chance 'ing' is added to a stopword list either within magento or elasticsearch itself? https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/search/search-stopwords.html?lang=en

Comment: I did not even know that file existed, thanks for the info. I'll run checks/tests now.

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this mystery?

Comment: Mystery was unresolved. Added a new extension which has been working well since :)